# Mostrar imagen de base datos

Tags: php, mysql

se especifica en que campo se va a guardar la imagen en la base de datos, osea el campo archive.

```
'archive' => sanitize(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['archive']['tmp_name']))),
```

al ver el campo en la base de datos sale que se llena de la siguiente forma

```
[BLOB - 3.0 KB]
```

bien por el momento, ahora lo que quiero es mostrarla, lo intente de la siguiente forma.

```
<td class="text-center"><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row->archive);?>"></td>
```

$row tiene la consulta para traer la info, funciona porque ya estoy mostrando otros campos.

al cargar la pagina la imagen sale rota y el src sale de la siguiente forma.

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,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">
```

que estoy haciendo mal, la forma en que se inserta o la forma en que lo llamo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estás modificando el contenido del archivo con esta línea:

```
'archive' => sanitize(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['archive']['tmp_name']))),
```

No sé que hagas en la función sanitize, no la necesitas para este campo y estoy seguro que con addslashes estás tratando de evitar errores en consultas e inyección SQL, pero no es el método adecuado.

En tu otra pregunta estás usando mysqli por procedimientos, entonces solo debes escapar el contenido, sin modificarlo:

```
'archive' => mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['archive']['tmp_name'])),
```

En cuanto a la forma de mostrar la imagen:

```
<td class="text-center"><img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($row->archive);?>"></td>
```

Si verificaste que realmente se trata de una imagen jpg (no gif, no png, ni otro tipo de archivo) y guardaste correctamente el archivo, no deberías tener problema.

Comment: puse la linea como indico pero ahora el src solo sale asi "data:image/jpg;base64,"

Comment: es decir la imagen no se guarda